# iris segmentation using canny ang Hough circular

Tags: python, image-processing

i am working on authentication system that based on iris, iam using iris casia v.1 data set , i am trying to segment the iris part of the eye using canny edge detection an  circular Hough transform but i couldn't get it fit

```
# Read the image in grayscale

image = cv2.imread(file_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Remove Gaussian noise
image = remove_gaussian_noise(image)

# Remove salt and pepper noise
preprocessed_image = remove_salt_pepper_noise(image)

# Resize image for consistency
preprocessed_image = cv2.resize(preprocessed_image, (128, 128))

equalized_image = cv2.equalizeHist(preprocessed_image)

# Display the original and equalized images
cv2.imshow('Original Image', image)
cv2.imshow('Equalized Image', equalized_image)
image_test1 = cv2.Canny(equalized_image, 10, 70, apertureSize=3)

# Display the Canny Edge Detection result
cv2.imshow("canny-2", image_test1)

# Define the output image on which to draw
output = equalized_image.copy()  # Create a copy of the equalized image for drawing

# Detect circles using Hough Circles
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image_test1, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 800,
                           param1=50, param2=20, minRadius=0, maxRadius=60)

# Ensure circles were found
if circles is not None:
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        # Draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        # Draw a rectangle (bounding box) around the detected circle
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 2, y - 2), (x + 2, y + 2), (0, 128, 255), -1)

# Display the result with detected circles
cv2.imshow('detected circles', output)
```

Comment: Even though you've provided the name of the data set, please post a link to a particular image, and then a link for one or more stages of immediate processing results. If I recall you can't embed images until you have enough reputation, but you can provide links. And briefly: you'll probably need an elliptical fit rather than a circle fit. Most circles aren't viewed at a purely perpendicular angle. Circle fits typically don't work well on images of natural objects such as eyes. That said, you'd made a good start on your first post!